# group by and subtract value of a given group from values of any other group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, group-by, aggregate

I have a data table, `data`, I want to group them by `group_label`
and subtract value of a group form that of other groups.

In other words, I want to subtract all "NYC" values in any group by
the value of NYC in group B.

I want to subtract any value associated with LA, in any group,
from the value of LA associated with LA in group B. so my result looks like
`result`. How can I do that?

```
    data = data.table(city = c("NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "LA", "LA", "LA"),
                  group_label = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C"),
                  time_period = c(1980, 1990, 2000, 1982, 2007, 2010),
                  value = c(2, 20, 13, 24, 4, 6)
                  )


result = data.table(city = c("NYC", "NYC", "NYC", "LA", "LA", "LA"),
                  group_label = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C"),
                  value = c(2, 20, 13, 24, 4, 6),
                  time_period = c(1980, 1990, 2000, 1982, 2007, 2010),
                  diff = c(-11, 7, 0, 0, -20, -18)
                  )
```

Answer (score 2):

An option would be

```
data[, diff := value - value[group_label == "B"],  city]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   group_by(city) %>%
   mutate(diff = value - value[group_label == "B"])
```

Comment: I am sorry, let me change the question. Because I am grouping by more than one column. I did it with one here to simplify things.

Do you have a solution that works when grouping with more than one column? 
I already saw this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043708/subtraction-within-groups-using-r

Comment: @NoLie. Isn't your question. about ssubtracting 'value' from the value' in 'group_label' 'B" for each 'city?

Comment: @NoLie. If it is multiple columns, `data %>% group_by(city1, city2, ...) %>%`

Comment: @NoLie. Only thing to consider is have 'B' 'group_label' for each 'city' and have only one. value per group.  Otherwise, may need some logicla condition

Comment: you are right! thanks a lot. I thought if columns other than `city` are not in the group by, then they will be eliminated from the `result`! which is not the case.

Thanks

Comment: @NoLie. `mutate` creates/modifies a column, while. `transmute` only returns the columns within that block, also `summarise` does the same i.ee  returns only the columnss summarised along with grouping column